# javascript RegExp pattern change after used with test() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple pattern that validate Time - 24 Hours Mode -

```
var patt = /^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/g;
```

If i execute this pattern with `.test()` method twice i get two different values

Like This

*CODE*

```
console.log(patt.test('01:09')); // true
console.log(patt.test('01:09')); // false
```

i have notice that if i do the following i get the same result :

```
var patt = /^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/g; 
console.log(patt.test('01:09')); // true

var patt = /^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/g; 
console.log(patt.test('01:09'));//true
```

**Question**
i'll re-initiate the `patt` object as a work around in my case but i'm very curious to know what happens

*Also i notice that `patt` object doesn't change after using it with `test()` Method*

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYZCv/) for those how want to prove something

Comment: From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test): *" As with `exec` (or in combination with it), `test` called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `global` flag. Currently it's searching at the end of your input string for the second time, where it won't find the pattern again. See [docs for the `lastIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex).